# SpringBoot JPA Interface's save() and delete() not working with ArrayList or Long

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, interface, spring-data-jpa

I am following a tutorial that uses SpringBoot 1.3. I am on the latest release of SpringBoot 2.0. I am working on creating an REST API. I need help adapting the 1.3 code to 2.0 compliance as `save()` and `delete()` now expect objects over `long id`s. **How do I need to rewrite the interface to accept `long id' and 'ArrayList`?**

Here's the code as it stands:

### The Base Object

```
@Entity
public class HotelBooking {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private long id; // could be Long

private String hotelName;
private double pricePerNight;
private int nbOfNights;

public HotelBooking(){} 

public HotelBooking(String hotelName, double pricePerNight, int nbOfNights) {
    this.hotelName = hotelName;
    this.pricePerNight = pricePerNight;
    this.nbOfNights = nbOfNights;
}
// getters omitted
}
```

### The Interface

```
@Repository
public interface BookingRepository extends JpaRepository<HotelBooking, Long> {
data/jpa/docs/2.1.0.M1/reference/html/
    List<HotelBooking> findByPricePerNightLessThan(double price);
}
```

### Using a `long id` to delete an entry in the `database`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/id")
public List<HotelBooking> remove(@PathVariable long id) {
    bookingRepository.delete(id);
    return bookingRepository.findAll();
}
```

### Trying to save an ArrayList object to the `database`

```
 @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        List<HotelBooking> bookings = new ArrayList<>();

        bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Marrior", 200.50, 3));
        bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Ibis", 90, 4));
        bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Novotel", 140.74, 1));

        bookingRepository.save(bookings);
    }
```

### The Problem

The above do not work in SpringBoot 2.0 anymore. **When trying to delete via ID** I get an error saying - `Error:(61, 34) java: incompatible types: long cannot be converted to romaniancoder.booking.HotelBooking`
It is now expecting an object instead of a `long id` to find an object in the database.

When **trying to save an ArrayList I get this error** - `Error:(40, 26) java: method save in interface org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository<T,ID> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: S
  found: java.util.List<romaniancoder.booking.HotelBooking>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: java.util.List<romaniancoder.booking.HotelBooking>
    upper bound(s): romaniancoder.booking.HotelBooking`
It's as if it needs a class extended or something to work? I am not sure...

After reading the Spring Docs I don't understand why this changed and how I can write code to accept a `long id` to find something in the `database`. I don't understand how to adapt `save()` to accept `ArrayLists`.

Comment: You can use repository.deleteById(Long) and repository.saveAll(ArrayList).

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly the answer I needed. Where would I have been able to find this myself? I haven't found a doc that lists all the available functions of SpringBoot.

Comment: These changes are introduced in SpringBoot 2.0 and IDE autocompletion shows these new methods.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `repository.deleteById(Long)` and `repository.saveAll(ArrayList)`. These methods are introduced in SpringBoot 2.0.

Comment: Similar for me...but different method. I was getting compilation rashes because findOne now returns Optional. Might need to change old "findOne" to new "getOne". https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html